# Is it possible to make an array with dynamic memory using while loop without asking the size of memory from user?

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm trying to make a programme that it doesn't ask user the value i, where i being the number of elements of an array, ( `int[] someArray = new int[i]`).
 Two problems i'm facing , first how the programme auto locates memory size , and second one is, facing trouble with different types of data( i know this one is trivial but just could't put together the logic).
  Basically my programme structure is like below:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int[] someArray;
int element;
String order;

while(!("done").equals(order=input.nextLine())){

   if(some integer){

   //set the user input as the value of array element, and change the pointer to the next element
   }

  if(some string other than "done"){

  System.out.println();
  //continues the loop

   }


}
```

Comment: Better use arraylist, if you still beginner for arrayList, check this out. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use an already existing growing collection, such as `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, etc. You add as many elements as you want and they take care of dynamically allocating the necessary space.

Answer (score 0):

This is called dynamic resizing and has the amortized complexity O(n). 
The main idea is to double the array size every time your array gets full.
For implementation details I would take a look [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java).

PS: don't forget to mark some answers for your questions as SOLVED, as it seems that you never do that.